# QualComm Vuforia Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

i m new to Augmented Reality i`ve downloaded the Vuforia Skd for android for AR but it is not working as there are multiple C/c++ files. 
how can run the project on eclipse 
do i need NDK for this 
if so can any one share the tutorial for this how to work with NDK 
any help/suggestion will be warmly welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found at my own 
do the following thing 
add the paths appropriately 
download the cygwin for c/c++ compilation and add its path to environment variable and while downloading the cygwin download the make from it 
after that compile the code using CMD and at the project path write ndk-build  for c/c++ files compilation and then run the code through eclipse it will work 
for further detail 
Use this   https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality

Answer (score 4):

I think the guidelines on this page were very clear.

https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk

Always before running your program you have to compile the c++ code separately, and then clean and run it in Eclipse.